# POST a list to the API, update or create depending on the existence of that instance

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a view which allows me to post multiple entries to a model. Currently if I add all new entries, they are added successfully. But if I add any entry for which the pk already exists, it naturally throws a serializer error and nothing gets updated.

I wish to write a method which will let me post multiple entries, but automatically either update an existing one OR add a new one successfully depending the existence of that instance.

The idea of a customized ListSerialzer is the closest thing I came across to achieve this but still not clear if I can do this.

Has anyone ever implemented anything like this ?

In views.py:

```
def post(self,request,format=None):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = PanelSerializer(data=data,many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse({"success":"true","content":serializer.data}, status=201)
    return JsonResponse({'success': "false",'errorCode':"1",'errorMessage':serializer.errors}, status=400)
```

in serializers.py:

```
  class PanelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         class Meta:
         model = Panel
         fields = ('pId','pGuid','pName', 'pVoltage', 'pAmperage','pPermission', 'pPresent', 'pSelf','pInfo')

     def create(self, validated_data):
        logger.info('Information incoming_1!')
        print ("Atom")
        return Panel.objects.create(**validated_data)

     def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.pId = validated_data.get('pId', instance.pId)
        instance.pGuid = validated_data.get('pId', instance.pGuid)
        instance.pName = validated_data.get('pName', instance.pName)
        instance.pVoltage = validated_data.get('pVoltage', instance.pVoltage)
        instance.pAmperage = validated_data.get('pAmperage', instance.pAmperage)
        instance.pPermission = validated_data.get('pPermission', instance.pPermission)
        instance.pPresent = validated_data.get('pPresent', instance.pPresent)
        instance.pSelf = validated_data.get('pSelf', instance.pSelf)
        instance.pInfo = validated_data.get('pInfo', instance.pInfo)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

This is how the code stands as of now. I believe I will mainly need to either work on the update method of my serializer or first change it to a ListSerializer and write some custom logic again in the update method.

Comment: To be more precise, after exactly trying what I wanted to by altering the above code, I get the following error:

Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify the behavior exactly.

Thus I wanted to see an implementation of what has been described above for more clarity.

Comment: This approach is completely extraneous to REST. So rest framework is a bad choice for this task. It is easier to take some serializer library and make usual django view. Or as an option, you can make 2 requests on save. POST for new records and PUT/PATCH for existing ones.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to change my approach unless I see a running example somewhere. Thanks for the reply! 

I tried implementing the ListSerializer approach but I don't understand it completely, just looking at the example given in the documentation.